# How can I clear default highlighted gray color on list item in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swiftui, swiftui-list

I can't change the highlighted color of the `List` item, in UIKit Id change easily `TableViewCell`'s `Selection` property element *Default* to *None*. I can't find a solution for such a simple interaction, is there something that I missing?

Thank you.

Edit: I tried this but not worked.

```
NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(detail: self.viewModel.characters.results[index])) {  

CharacterCell(character: self.viewModel.characters.results[index])
                                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove highlight on tap of List with SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56545444/how-to-remove-highlight-on-tap-of-list-with-swiftui)

Comment: Nope, not worked. :/

Answer (score 0):

Add the code to a init()

```
   init() {
        // Set selected (onTapped) background color of cell.
        let color = UIView()
        color.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = color
    }
```

For example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SomeView: View {

    init() {
        // Set selected (onTapped) background color of cell.
        let color = UIView()
        color.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = color
    }

    var body: some View {

        // Your List/ForEach code
        Text(/"Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

I have noticed that swiftUI preview doesn't show the change, but inside the simulator or running on a device you will see the effect.

In your case, you would set the UIColor.clear and this should eliminate the gray as required.